# Creating new worlds with different users on Xbox One

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am very new to Minecraft, but have found that this game is rather addicting at times. A friend of mine wanted to start their own world on my Xbox One, so they logged in with their gamertag and loaded up Minecraft.

We found they were able to play the tutorial, but couldn't create a new world. I haven't been able to find anything in my research that says this can't be done. Can only one gamertag on Xbox One create a new world in Minecraft?

Comment: Do you have an account or do you have a demo version?

Comment: @genesis943 Yes I have an account, it's my Xbox One with the full version of the game.

Answer (score 1):

On Xbox One, only the user that owns the game can play the full version of said game. This is most likely the issue.

EDIT: Sorry for being *so* late, but can you make sure that console is your Home Xbox? You can do this by going into the console's System Settings menu. If it's your Home Xbox, the problem may be fixed. **Please note** that you can only do this 3 times **every 365 days**.